# Is it possible to integrate Spring MVC with Guice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, integration, guice

It's probably a dumb question for the experts in Spring MVC but I don't know how does it work under the hood that's why I ask.

Another wording for the same question: are there any dependencies on Spring DI inside Spring MVC?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [google-sitebricks](http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's not possible to use Spring MVC without the IOC container.

For example: at the heart of Spring MVC lies the [`DispatcherServlet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet). DispatcherServlet 
initializes itself using these methods:

```
/**
 * This implementation calls {@link #initStrategies}.
 */
@Override
protected void onRefresh(ApplicationContext context) {
    initStrategies(context);
}

/**
 * Initialize the strategy objects that this servlet uses.
 * <p>May be overridden in subclasses in order to initialize
     * further strategy objects.
 */
protected void initStrategies(ApplicationContext context) {
    initMultipartResolver(context);
    initLocaleResolver(context);
    initThemeResolver(context);
    initHandlerMappings(context);
    initHandlerAdapters(context);
    initHandlerExceptionResolvers(context);
    initRequestToViewNameTranslator(context);
    initViewResolvers(context);
}
```

So you can see, everything is tightly integrated with the `ApplicationContext` interface.

So your only chance would be to have a Guice implementation of ApplicationContext, and that would be very far-fetched, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to use some of the more primitive Spring MVC functionality without using the Spring IOC container - this is, after all, the whole point of IoC.

It's going to be difficult, though, since many of the Spring MVC components use the Spring-proprietary lifecycle callbacks (e.g. `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean`) which Guice won't know about. You'd have to handle those yourself.

A better question, though, is *why* would you want to do this?  Without Spring IoC being used, Spring MVC loses most of its appeal. I don't see why you would want to use one without the other.

Comment: I cannot afford using Spring in the cloud - it takes too long to start-up a new instance. And I need some MVC for the front-end development. Another options are Struts, Stripes and my own simple MVC implementation.

Comment: Struts2 integrates nicely with Guice. I've heard some good things about Stripes, as well (not sure how well it integrates with Guice).

Answer (score 1):

a side-by-side solution: http://www.earldouglas.com/guice-with-a-spring-twist